# Syncing Route 53 static website to github website repository (allowing offline/destop editing)

Tags: amazon-s3, github-pages, amazon-route53

I have had a github.io website for quite some time, and want to move it over to it's own domain name. Currently, I have transferred all the files to the right S3 bucket and I can access the website all the same as I can my Github. However, I want to be able to edit individual files in a desktop app (such as SubEthaEdit or Brackets), like you can in Github, which to my knowledge you cant.

I would like to be able to migrate the Github website over to the domain name, so that when I edit, save, and push a commit from the Github desktop using SubEthaEdit, it would be automatically updated on the domain website (ideally). Either this, or they share a library that is still accessible from the Github desktop app. I really just hate editing files using S3's editor, or having to download and re-upload any document I am working on.

Im quite new to any sort of coding or programming languages other than a little bit of javascript, apologies if the language I used is, shall I say, sub-par.

Comment: https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site

Comment: Perfect use for CodePipeline and CodeBuild/CodeDeploy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got It!

@ceejayoz helped to point me in the right direction.

after some fiddling, I got a CNAME record that points towards my github website, while maintaining https.